# A question about limit at infinity

Tags: calculus

I am calculating an average of n quantities, each of which is greater than 1. However, as $n\to \infty$, the value approaches 1. Hence, I expect the average > 1.

But, after applying limits to the average and doing some approximations, I got

$f(n) < f_1(n) =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{g(n) + n+c}{n}$ where c is a constant independent of $n$, and f(n) is the average value that I am seeking.

However, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{g(n)}{n} = 0$

Hence, $f(n) < \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+c}{n}$, which is 1.

But, since each of the values was greater than 1, I expect the average value to be $\ge$ 1, or in this case, exactly 1.

But clearly, the limits yield $f(n) < 1$.
How can I argue that the value of $f(n)$ is exactly 1, and not less than 1?

Comment: if all the values approach 1, their average should also approach 1. I guess the problem is how you got your strict inequality $f(n)<f_1(n)$. Donc forget that when giong to the limit, strict inequalities become large inequalities

Comment: This is exactly I am seeking! Can you explain how?

Comment: this answer (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/562738/) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You did not give enough information for us to see where the mistake is.

My guess is that you obtained $f(n)<f_1(n)$, and that you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_1(n)=1$, so you concluded $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)<1$.
This is wrong, because this only allows you to conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)\leq 1$.

This is because when you have to converging sequence $u_n$ and $v_n$ such that $u_n<v_n$, then you only can say $\lim u_n\leq \lim v_n$. For instance think of $u_n=-\frac{1}{n}$ and $v_n=\frac{1}{n}$. For all $n$ we have $u_n<v_n$, but both limits are $0$.

Answer (score 0):

From $f(n)<f_1(n)$ you can only get $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\le \lim_{n\to\infty}f_1(n)$ (if the limits exist at all).

Comment: The limit does exist, and I know that value of limit to $f(n)$ at infinity has to be 1 intuitively, but how do I argue about that?