# $\epsilon, \delta$...So what?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, definition, education

Over the course of my studies I often encounter phrases in reference material of the type *"and this avoids the need for using $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definitions"* or *"by this we can omit those complicated $\epsilon, \delta$ arguments"*, etc. In other words performing stunts in order to get around $\epsilon, \delta$. I've seen enough of this to think that it should be categorized as *epsilondeltophobia*, if you all will permit. Personally, I was thrilled to learn definitions in these terms because it was one of the first rigorous definitions given to me, all in terms of quantifier logic, *and* it was used for very fundamental things whose real meaning I always wondered about. In the beginning of course I didn't have a clue how to use the language, but I loved it anyways because it was like, "wooow, *deep* maan". Not to mention that later on, I began to see that all of the higher-order constructions that were built upon $\epsilon, \delta$-objects worked out perfectly, giving me more satisfaction that whoever came up with $\epsilon, \delta$ language knew what they were doing. So I'm not saying that it's not ok to develop an *epsilondeltophobia*, as we all do naturally in the beginning...but textbooks (some) seem to promote this fear, even some teachers, and this is what I'm not happy about. I think $\epsilon, \delta$ is great.

Question: who thinks likewise? oppositely?

Edit: I don't want this to come off as a pedantic "rigor or death" statement, or as a suggestion that first courses on calculus should always include $\epsilon, \delta$ (although maybe yes in mathematics). I'm just against the predisposal to it in a negative way.

Comment: Examples please? Where have you encountered this?

Comment: Jee well I can't remember specific books, it's just a notion I've developed from having paged through many many things

Comment: at least give the context - a physics book? calculus chapters on derivatives?

Comment: I agree that you need to give examples.If you want to prove anything about limits, you need to use $\varepsilon,\delta$ (or $\varepsilon,N$ for sequences)

Comment: Well, I do recall that one of these was in a book about nonlinear optimization... and then a bunch of pdf's on calc-1. I'm not saying that $\epsilon, \delta$ should always be standard in a first calculus course (though later on it should), I just don't get the negative predisposing of it

Comment: To avoid the opinion-based hold, you can perhaps focus your question on the advantages, disadvantages, and possibly alternatives to $\epsilon,\delta$ "definitions" in introductory (for a general audience?) math courses.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov If they want to hold then let them, it just saddens me. I asked the question with intent and worked on it to get precisely the type of well-worked answers and counterarguments that have appeared so far... changing it would be lying, like a child made to say "I'm sorry" and just says it, but doesn't feel it.

Comment: I might suggest some of Terry Tao's blogs about non-standard analysis and "epsilon management" as instances of this, though he hardly has a "phobia" of hard analysis.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ proofs are like assembly languages. As soon as you have a higher-level command for a loop, you should not program a loop in assembly language because it is both hard to do and both hard to understand. In the same vein, you use the definition to prove properties of limits and continuous functions and then you use these properties instead of the definition. This has nothing whatsoever to do with lack of rigor. It is possible to give more and less rigorous proofs with and without lower-case Greek letters.

Comment: @Phira I completely get what you mean about assembly language, I always mentally make the same analogy. But precisely in the same spirit is why I think $\epsilon, \delta$ is marvelous, because it's a "low-level" structure that works perfectly for the "high-level" objects you wanted to create later on, and this is generally a hard thing to accomplish, seeing as who knows how changes at low-level affect later constructions. Also I didn't mean that $\epsilon, \delta$ should be the one and only way to prove things, of course it makes sense to use properties once they're proven.

Comment: @GPerez But it is more than that. The key issue is to choose the "right" properties to prove. If you later need $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ again, this is a sign that you are missing an appropriate general property. This can give the impression of phobia, but it is an important heuristic.

Comment: @Phira Of course, otherwise we'd all be using $\epsilon, \delta$ to calculate integrals, and nobody wants that. I guess what I really mean is: $\epsilon, \delta$ proofs are a great exercise in proofs and logic, they serve as an introduction to such things, and nobody will be harmed in being exposed to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that is a complex issue; we have both *pedagocical* aspects and "foundational" ones.

First, according to my point of view, and assuming that I'm not prepared to discuss the pedagogical side, I think that we cannot avoid in teaching mathematics (and not only) some amount of "dogmatism". Past failure in the efforts to introduce naive set language in advance to elementary arithmetics was significative.

Try for a moment with this "conceptual experiment" : teaching in secondary school algebra and calculus starting from axiomatized $ZF$ and building all mathematical stuff "from scratch" (the empty set) . Do we really think it feasible ?

A recent book by **John Stilwell**, *The Real Numbers An Introduction to Set Theory and Analysis* (2013), start with the following consideration :

> any book that revisits the foundations of analysis has to reckon with the formidable precedent of Edmund Landau’s *Grundlagen der Analysis* (Foundations of Analysis) of 1930. [...] so few books since 1930 have even attempted to include the construction of the
>   real numbers in an introduction to analysis. On the one hand, Landau’s account is
>   virtually the last word in rigor. [...] On the other hand, Landau’s book is almost pathologically reader-unfriendly.

I've tried re-reading Landau : it is **very** "unfriendly" !

Second : please, don't forget the enormous amount of effort it takes, form Newton and Leibniz until (at least) Cauchy (see the wonderful book of Judith Grabiner, *The Origins of Cauchy's Rigorous Calculus* - 1981) to "distill" the rigorous $(\epsilon − \delta)$ definition! And also mathematical standards of "rigor" are evolving.

I spoke above about "dogmatism" (suggestion : think how to apply Thomas Khun's considerations in *SSR* about the "positive" role of dogmatism in "normal science" to mathematics).

My personal feeling is that the best antidote to the (unavoidable) use of dogmatism in teaching is the historical perspective: to learn *how* we arrived at current ideas (included *our* current standard of rigor and *our* current ideas about "foundations") can be very useful.

Comment: Regarding the "conceptual experiment", I think it'd be very positive if the definition of a vector space over a field were somehow introduced in high-school, and elementary proofs like $\lambda v = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = 0 \text{ or } v=0$, because it's relatively simple, yet rigorous at the same time. I don't know... I just like the concept of not talking about something until you define what you're talking about. Logically, a balance has to be found, otherwise we'd all be reading Lanadu before learning to count.

Comment: Also, about the historical perspective, yes yes and yes. Because we always get the format: axioms$\to$definitions$\to$theorems, as if it happened that way chronologically, whereas the real diagram is probably the most complex of directed graphs, if it were simplified.

Answer (score 20):

I believe that the pushback against *$\epsilon,\delta$ definitions* (which unfortunately spills over to pushback against *$\epsilon,\delta$ techniques*) is entirely justified because *$\epsilon,\delta$ definitions* arise from the (unfortunately widespread) confusion between a statement being *formal* and a statement being *rigorous*.

Consider the *formal "definition"* of continuity of a function $f$ at a point $a$:
$$\forall\epsilon\exists\delta\forall x(0<|x-a|<\delta\rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon)$$ This is just an objuscated way of stating the informal, but rigorous:

> For every ball $B_{f(a)}$ centered at $f(a)$, there is a ball $B_a$ centered at $a$ so that $f$ sends every point of $B_a$ into $B_{f(a)}$.

which is logically equivalent to the conceptually clearer, though still informal, though still rigorous:

> Whenever the image $f(S)$ of a set $S$ is separated from the image $f(a)$ of a point $a$, the set $S$ was already separated from the point $a$.

which is the contrapositive of the, informal and rigorous, *intuitive definition* of continuity of $f$ at a point $a$:

> Whenever a set $S$ of points are close to a point $a$, the set of images $f(S)$ of those points are close to image point $f(a)$.

I strongly believe that the equivalence of the blocked statements and the IDEA that equivalence expresses, which is that we CAN distill an intuitive notion into a rigorous definition, is much more interesting, important, and memorable, than the formal $\epsilon,\delta$ "definition". Furthermore, I can't even bring myself to calling the formal "definition" a definition, since what it expresses is not a description of what it *means* for a function to be continuous, but a technique (of $\epsilon,\delta$ proofs) for how to *check* that a function is continuous.

This, in my opinion, is *the reason* for the pushback against $\epsilon,\delta$ "definition" and arguments: instead of expressing the rigorous idea or concept of continuity, the $\epsilon,\delta$ "definition" only gives a technique for working with continuity, and, when presented as a definition, only obfuscates the meaning of the concept (in a very efficient way, I might add, since the path from the intuitive and meaningful definition to the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition involves taking a contrapositive...).

Finally, I do think that being aware of how to rigorously translate (as above) from the intuitive definition of continuity to the statement of the $\epsilon,\delta$ technique will certainly not hurt, and I suspect could actually help students in using the ($\epsilon,\delta$) technique, especially with the simple functions that arise in Calculus and basic analysis.

(Someone might criticize the above saying that the notion of a ball is confusing in single-variable Calculus. My perhaps controversial response is that there really isn't any good reason not to teach Calculus using $2$ or $3$ variables from day $1$ and that the narrow viewpoint offered by single-variable Calculus obscures more than it simplifies).

Comment: It's okay though, I mean accepting $\epsilon,\delta$ as a definition doesn't mean prohibition of developing intuitions about what it means. Personally I always made [this diagram](http://i.imgur.com/KLz4hTo.png) (thank you geogebra) mentally whenever imagining it. As a side note what is "what something means" if not the definition we have decided for it?

Comment: The intuitions, hence the meaning, come before the definitions. That's just how mathematical practice is, and one's choice of definitions reflects either one's active preference for some intuitions, or one's complacent (unexamined) acceptance of other intuitions...

Comment: Why of course I'm complacent in accepting these intuitions, I happen to agree with them. And maybe we have conceptions a priori in our minds, but until you define what it means, you can't "do things" with them.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for your response. I could not agree more. $\epsilon, \delta$ are just a shorthand notation to save typing effort in place of their equivalent statements in English (or whatever language the student is being taught in). For me $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ means that the values of $f$ can be made arbitrarily near to $L$ by choosing values of $x$ sufficiently near to $a$ (but not equal to $a$). And there is nothing non-rigorous in the last statement. To me $\epsilon, \delta$ is a sign of formalism and not rigor.

Comment: A sample example of rigor and its translation into formalism is in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/562738/

Comment: I'm not sure "rigorous" and "formal" are exactly the right words to use (I admit that the word "rigorous" in math has become a pet peeve of mine; I'm no longer sure *what* it means), but I find the sentiment of this answer dead-on.  Calculus textbooks approach the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition by emphasizing formal algebraic manipulations of inequalities, which seems especially cruel since anyone who teaches calculus knows that students are absolutely untrained in and bad at this.  So the underlying geometric/topological meaning is lost, despite the fact that it could be easier to understand.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that engineers, scientists, and financial folks need to use calculus, but they don't need to understand calculus.

The construction of the typical university education feeds all of those students, plus math students, through the same introductory calculus courses. This is done for cost efficiency, and also because of a potentially mis-placed ideal that career mathematicians should teach mathematics to people for whom mathematics is ultimately really just an annoying means to an end.

So eliding $\epsilon - \delta$ arguments streamlines this process, saving trouble for the students and the instructors, at the expense of the math students. But those math students will encounter it later, anyways.

I'm not saying it's the best approach, but it's a bit more efficient perhaps. Mechanical engineers don't want to learn $\epsilon - \delta$, and math professors don't want to teach $\epsilon - \delta$ to students who will never truncate a Taylor series beyond the linear term.

Comment: As I say to my students: "If you don't understand it, you are not allowed to use it".

Comment: As is the state of things, math is in fact an annoying means to an end for a lot of people. I hope you'll agree that this is not desirable. Now I'm not saying someday we'll live in a magical world where everyone from all disciplines loves math as well, but if we can at least move towards an education where abstractions and the occasional formal definition are not refused or feared by learners, that would be quite ok. I mean without these you can end up arguing over terms that were never defined and nobody actually knows what they're talking about and it's all just a big mess.

Comment: @GPerez I don't know. In principle valuing abstraction is attractive to us as mathematicians. But if you were a hairdresser, you'd want people to value the art and science of hair care. Ultimately, I just want a haircut, and so I pay a professional who does understand those things to do it for me. I appreciate what they do, but I will never appreciate it enough to study it. So it goes for mathematics, too.

Comment: It's not just a "misplaced ideal", but also a practical necessity.  Because math departments teach calculus, and because many (in some schools most or even all) students are required to *take* calculus, the math department becomes hugely important.  If calculus-for-engineers were outsourced to the engineers, math departments would probably have about the same stature as philosophy departments.

Comment: @Ryan Reich what do you mean by stature? Also keep in mind college works differently all around the world.

Comment: @GPerez I mean importance to the administration.

Comment: @Arkamis You're probably right, but I meant more in the fields of physics,engineering,biology, etc. Surely abstraction is fundamental to any science. But wait! It's important in literature, for example, too! One abstracts in order to analyze what a book or story is trying to get across. In music I can't even begin to list the ways in which abstraction from multiple, seemingly different songs to the concept of *a* song, viewed as chord progressions, scales which go along with each chord or key, things called "modes", etc. I don't think many can be saved from using abstract definitions

Comment: I think it's important to recall that, historically, the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition came more than a hundred years so after the initial development of calculus.  One would guess from this that the definition is not completely obvious, although it seems like it after the fact.  It's also some seems to be evidence that it's possible to use calculus for practical purposes without a completely rigorous foundation by modern mathematicians' standards.

Comment: @JairTaylor, you can have a completely rigorous foundation *and* infinitesimals.

Comment: @user72694, that's true, I've heard you can, although I've never studied that myself.  But I believe the current theory of infinitesimals in nonstandard analysis is pretty different from the original nonrigorous thinking of Newton, Leibniz and co.

Comment: @JairTaylor, the hyperreals are rather different from Newton's various approaches, but there are important similarities with Leibniz's approach; see [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10670-012-9370-y). Whether or not Leibniz's thinking was "nonrigorous" depends on what exactly you mean by that; if you mean that Leibniz did not use Cantorian set theory, then you are certainly right. If you mean that Leibniz's procedures are very different from hyperreal procedures, you will find information to the contrary in the article. If you mean that Leibniz's approach contained...

Comment: ...logical contradictions, then arguably this is a persistent error of calculus historiography; see the article cited above.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the info!  I suppose I was under the impression that a lot of confusion from the era stemmed from not maintaining a clear distinction between definitions and theorems - e.g., debates about whether imaginary numbers and infinitesimals "really existed" or not, which lead to a lot of nonrigorous reasoning by modern standards.  But I haven't looked much into Leibniz's views, so perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: "It turns out that engineers, scientists, and financial folks need to use calculus, but they don't need to understand calculus." Wow, what a clear statement of what seems implicitly to be the dominant position in the contemporary pedagogy of freshman calculus...and which I find to be alarming and pernicious bordering on repugnant.  I wish we college math teachers could have an explicit discussion to see whether we really believe this and fully understand its implications.

Comment: Two opening salvos: (i) Both real world exposure to young people and much research bears out the hypothesis that almost everyone begins their study of (e.g.) mathematics wanting to understand everything.  The tragedy of mathematics education is that we beat this desire out of 99% of the students so systematically and thoroughly that by the time they get to calculus they have a Stockholm syndrome level identification with their torturers. (ii) In contemporary society, the name for the thing that does calculations without conceptual understanding is "computer", not "engineer".

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Indeed. I think it's sad (at best) and dangerous (at worst), but I have a hard time convincing myself that it's not true. As a career engineer, most of my contemporaries can do calculus, but cannot do epsilon-delta proofs. And honestly, they do not need to. Engineering is more than computation. Engineering is about judgment and design and decision making. Adding technical rigor doesn't necessarily *directly* improve those things. I'd rather the chemical engineer who designs my shampoo have a good understanding of risks and proper mixing and safety.

Comment: That said, engineers also recognize this deficiency, and good firms do hire mathematicians (which is how I ended up with the title 'Engineer'). Nevertheless, there are plenty of mathematically-deficient engineers who should absolutely not be; recently, I had to explain the Riemann-Stieltjes integral to someone who professed himself to be an expert in game theory. That's just kind of sad.

Comment: @Arkamis: It is really unclear how much treatment of epsilon-delta is necessitated in order to "understand calculus", so it is a bit dangerous to use the former as a synecdoche for the latter.  (In particular, you say engineers do not need to do $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs: yes, I agree.)  When I teach calculus, the desire to at least attempt to present the material in an intellectually coherent way leads me to present a positive, but very small (!!), amount of $\epsilon$-$\delta$...and I do so in a different and more geometric way than calculus textbooks seem to think is necessary for "rigor".

Comment: Let me also say -- if I can say something without wanting to back it up in these comments -- that I have often been less than favorably impressed with the amount of "understanding of calculus" evinced by the way calculus textbooks are written.  A lot of times what mathematics textbooks at this level call "rigor" I would be tempted to call "pedantry brought on by a limited, fragile understanding".

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I agree 100% with all of that. Epsilon-delta is just one part of understanding, and not the complete picture. Nevertheless, I think you'd be appalled if you tracked down some engineering students, asked them to compute the derivative of a function, and then asked them to explain the definition of a derivative.

Comment: It seems to me that for the engineer it is especially important to be able to estimate the result they need, and to know how to compute to within a desired degree of accuracy.  The "exact" answer is rarely available, and for an approximation to be worth anything, it must be controlled ( accuracy to within 1 kilogram is very different from accuracy to within one gram).  Epsilon delta analysis is simply learning how to make rigorous error analysis.  I wish it were taught this way...

Comment: Arkamis: No "tracking down" will be necessary: I have taught and am currently teaching engineering students (and thus I cannot disagree with your assessment, unfortunately).  @Steven: yes, I wholeheartedly agree!  It took me a while to figure out that this is what applied analysis was actually about: controlled estimates rather than exact answers.  Last semester when I taught calculus I spent *several lectures* on numerical integration, I topic I had completely skipped in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately students are not well trained in estimation of any kind.  I remember well from last semester when I decided to strategically retreat from asking them any exam questions on Taylor's Theorem with Remainder (too hard; I would be testing degrees of rote memorization rather than any real understanding) in favor of the Alternating Series Error Estimate, which is so technically simple that there is nothing other than understanding the basic idea required.  Still it was a challenging topic...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark This discussion definitely highlights a need for dialog on the role of mathematics education at all levels. But I feel like a lot of mathematicians often get caught up in mathematics when these discussions come up, as if they feel the need to justify their existence by enforcing the teaching of concepts they feel important. I still maintain that an engineer or financial analyst does not need to understand calculus to the degree that a mathematician does. Nevertheless, there is much value in training these students in the practice of mathematical thinking.

Comment: And that holds true at all levels. Focus on what things *mean*, rather than how to *do* them. A good proxy of a measure of success for a mathematical curriculum would be to eliminate the question all mathematicians eventually get: "so what is it that you *do*?"

Comment: "I still maintain that an engineer or financial analyst does not need to understand calculus to the degree that a mathematician does."  Well, sure.  You could hardly become a mathematician without taking 5-10 additional deepening your understanding of various aspects of calculus.  I think that freshman calculus should not contain the aspects of abstraction or attention to foundational ideas that occurs even in later undergraduate courses.  But some idea that continuity means that the error in the output can be controlled arbitrarily well by restricting the input seems important.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Of course. But what's the solution? Textbooks suck. Curricula in a typical 4-year program are so compactified as to not allow any freedom for spending time on learning material beyond what is strictly necessary. Students don't care (and neither do employers -- worse, in many cases neither do graduate schools). What to do?

Comment: @Arkamis: Well, the first step is to identify and agree on the problem.  And then....can I get back to you?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark "When I teach calculus, the desire to at least attempt to present the material in an intellectually coherent way..." **This** sums up what I believe, that presenting mathematics without coherence, e.g. things deducted from others, proofs, is what ultimately leads to alienation from mathematics itself. When someone is capable of asking "is $\frac1{a+b}=\frac1a+\frac1b$?", they clearly have not learned what any of those operations mean, or else the answer would be obvious. That was a horrible example as it happens at an early level, where one is first learning math, but...

Comment: ... I hope you know the kind of thing I'm talking about. We could argue, as some have, that (insert_profession) doesn't need to *use*  an understanding of math. Well It depends on what we mean by "use"; A friend of mine teaches biology in a masters degree (where students are supposed to be at a level of conceptual maturity), and tells me that he finds it *impossible* to make his students understand the "epistemological hierarchy" of ideas, i.e. what concepts are deducted from others, in which order implications go, etc. He says that, rather, the material is just taken in as...

Comment: ... "loose bits of information", and therefore the students come up with equivalent questions (in biology) as the example two comments above. These students could or could have certainly *used* an education in mathematics such as is presented to a pure mathematician crowd. In other words, what he says is "*learn to reason, kid.*" So I'm not sure if (insert_profession) doesn't have to *use* an understanding of mathematics.

Answer (score 7):

$(\epsilon,\delta)$ techniques are fundamental to developing the foundations of real analysis, but sometimes insight can be gained via alternative techniques that one doesn't see as readily via $(\epsilon,\delta)$.  Consider for example the failure of the squaring function to be uniformly continuous. This is quite a tedious exercise to motivate if you are limited to $(\epsilon,\delta)$ techniques. Possibly 90% of undergraduates will be unable to reproduce such an exercise other than in a passive way.

An alternative possibility would be to note that $f(x)=x^2$ fails to be microcontinuous at a single infinite point $H$ and is therefore not uniformly continuous.  In this approach uniform continuity is defined by requiring $f$ to be microcontinuous at all points (standard and nonstandard) of its extended hyperreal domain.  Thus, if one considers an infinitesimal $\alpha=\frac{1}{H}$, then $f(H+\alpha)=H^2+2+\alpha^2$ and $f(H+\alpha)-f(H)=2+\alpha^2$ which is not infinitesimal. Thus we see that $f$ is not microcontinuous at $H$.

This definition makes it transparent that uniform continuity in this case has to do with the behavior of the function "at infinity".  This remark can be formalized in the context of an infinitesimal-enriched continuum, but cannot be formalized in the context of the real continuum.

Thus the $(\epsilon,\delta)$ approach has its advantages but it also has serious pedagogical shortcomings.

Comment: 1) Yes, uniform continuity is a killer. But, characterizations exists and they help.
2) As far as pedagogy goes, I disagree. Saving people from abstracting does not help them. Also, when somebody finally gets it, 100% of the time they feel really good about themselves. This is good. We want people to feel good about the things they are learning. Of course one asks: what if they don't get it? They will, eventually. The only problem is that not doing so on time has dire consequences, and so we turn to question how the whole testing and grading model is set up, but this is a different discussion.

Comment: @GPerez, as to 1): I precisely formulated such a "characterization", as you put it, and it helps. as to 2): I am not sure what you mean by "abstracting".  If you are referring to mathematical rigor, then the hyperreals are just as rigorous as the reals. The only "dire consequences" I see here is for people who refuse to consider alternatives.

Comment: I don't doubt that the hyperreals are valid, or abstract. In fact they are more abstract then the real numbers. But it all depends, do you want to give a mathematical education where everything is constructed and built upon, and proving steps along the way? In this case at some point you'd have to include a proof that the hyperreals are consistent if and only if the reals are. I don't know if it's complicated or not for students, if it weren't though then I'd have no complaints about this being used in mathematics education. If the education is to be given without proofs well, okay.

Comment: Taking the nonstandard analysis argument, and deleting some words and concepts, gives a simpler standard argument proving the same thing in the same way.  All the work consists of determining what scale of change to $H$ causes an appreciable change to $H^2$. There is nothing about NSA that would have indicated to choose $\alpha = 1/H$ as the infinitesimal, and the proof does not work with arbitrary $\alpha$.  The understanding of which choices work comes from the derivative, not foundations, though of course once you have a working argument it can be written in either language.

Comment: @GPerez, if you are talking about teaching calculus, you will agree with me that not everything "is constructed and built upon". Namely, calculus courses generally do not construct the real numbers from the rationals, as this material is more appropriate for later analysis courses. As far as the proof that the hyperreals are consistent if and only if the reals are, I can give you a short proof using nothing more than the material of a serious undergraduate algebra course.

Comment: @zyx, I appreciate the calm tone of your comment.  Which argument is simpler, the one based on the reals or the one based on the hyperreals, can certainly be discussed. I would start with the Cauchy's definition of continuity: a function is continuous at $x$ if every infinitesimal increment $\alpha$ always produces an infinitesimal change $f(x+\alpha)-f(x)$. See [Cours d'Analyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse).

Comment: @user72694 Maybe not, but at least axiomatically they are? The first couple of things I learned were things like "for every pair of different real numbers $a,b$, either $a<b$ or $a>b$, and other such properties. Shortly into the course the topic was successions, and I was shown that cauchy $\Rightarrow$ convergence. Maybe this is radically different in other schools, but would you agree it's a nice approach?

Comment: @GPerez, first of all, it is a very nice approach. But in the hyperreals it is just as true that ""for every pair of different real numbers $a,b$, either $a<b$ or $a>b$, and other such properties", by the [transfer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle). Moreover, the hyperreals can, and have been, similarly developed axiomatically.

Comment: @user72694 Then this matter becomes one of opinion, I for one prefer the reals :) I couldn't say why though, maybe a sense of nostalgia for formal 19th century mathematics? I don't know really

Comment: @GPerez, I am also excited about formal 19th century rigor. But it can hardly be said that the matter is one of opinion, since contrary to a popular perception the hyperreal framework is *not* meant as a replacement for the real framework but rather as an *extension* thereof.  Thus, all "real" techniques still apply (by the transfer principle), but one also has *new* techniques such as the possibility of defining continuity as "infinitesimal $dx$ produces infinitesimal $dy$", which are not available in the real framework. Also see...

Comment: ...[Terry Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Tao)'s writings about the expressive advantages of the hyperreal framework.

Comment: "Consider for example the failure of the squaring function to be uniformly continuous. This is quite a tedious exercise if you are limited to $(\epsilon,\delta)$ techniques." I disagree with this.  The *concept* of uniform continuity is one of the most difficult ones presented in undergrad courses.  But if you understand the concept, this calculation could hardly be more straightforward: $(x+\delta)^2-x^2 = 2x\delta + \delta^2$ cannot be bounded independently of $x$ because of the $x\delta$ term.  The NSA stuff is nice, but I *do* want students to be able to do this much "standard" analysis!

Comment: @Pete, in my experience of teaching calculus, the negations of the standard assertions are typically harder to deal with than the assertions themselves. I once had a TA at a large midwestern university who admitted to me that he did not know how to prove using epsilon, delta that the Heaviside function is discontinuous. Apart from this, the problem with the epsilon, delta definition of uniform continuity is that it gives you no inkling at all of the fact that the problem is *behavior at infinity*.  Go try to read *that* off the subtle phenomenon with quantifier order that distinguishes it from

Comment: ...regular continuity!  Then you begin to realize the student's nightmare.

Comment: Mikhail: You said that it was *quite a tedious exercise*.  My comment pointed out that this is not the case: the calculation is one of the easiest ones possible, and certainly no more or less onerous than $(H+\frac{1}{H})^2-H^2 = 2+ \frac{1}{H^2}$.  You also say that 90$\%$ of undergraduates will not be able to do this exercise.  That is not born out in my experience.  I think you actually mean that that percentage of students "does not really understand uniform continuity", which is more plausible if more nebulous.

Comment: My point is: you want to promote an NSA approach to calculus and analysis.  You have many good mathematical, pedagogical and historical points to make in support of this.  But when you resort to straw man type arguments -- look how complicated $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments are!  no one understands them, right? -- you are probably hurting your case, since most of your readers do understand $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments, in most cases (and quite naturally) better than the less standard stuff you are promoting.  So you need to take care not to exaggerate the difficulties, I think.

Comment: @Pete, perhaps I should have written that it is a "tedious exercise to motivate", since the relevant points are moving off to infinity. Obviously we are not merely talking about the formal verification that a suitable quantifier formula is satisfied. The point is the interpretation of that formula, and developing suitable intuitions to understand it. This is what students are having difficulties with.

Comment: @Pete, you are probably right that most SE editors are comfortable with epsilon, delta, but the point shouldn't be lost on them that a vast majority of their students aren't, and will never be if current trends continue.  This is a clear conclusion of all educational studies of this phenomenon.  If epsilon, delta were not the educational debacle that it is, pedagogy would be less of an effective argument in favor of the hyperreal approach, though there is still Terry Tao's argument in favor of its more expressive language and utility in research.

Comment: "Obviously we are not merely talking about the formal verification..." That was not obvious to me; maybe it will be obvious to others.  In terms of moving off to infinity: uniform continuity usually first appears in the context that a continuous function on a closed, bounded interval is necessarily uniformly continuous, and the above exercise is used primarily to explain that these hypotheses are necessary.  Again I do not find the standard story to be a nightmare to teach or to motivate. I mention that because you seem to expect that your readers will think so.

Comment: I very much like Terry Tao's approach, by the way: he clearly explains both standard and nonstandard analysis, is especially clear about the relations between them, and gives examples of which type of problem one might be preferred to the other.  He bears this out in his research, so it is clear that SA and NSA are both very useful for him.  I have never seen him say that hyperreals have "more expressive language and utility in research": his position is much more nuanced than that.

Comment: @Pete, thanks for your comment. It would be interesting to develop a suitable "question" concerning the situation on the ground with respect to teaching epsilon delta based on education field studies rather than anecdotal evidence. "Nightmare" is a strong word but in my experience students are frustrated by this sort of thing. It sounds like U Georgia applies high admission standards :-)

Comment: @Pete, when I spoke of Tao on expressive power, I was thinking of the kind of comment that's quoted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_nonstandard_analysis). Perhaps you can provide additional citations. He does not use the root "express" but the implication is clearly there.

Answer (score 5):

There's definitely something to @Arkamis's remarks (if they *are* somewhat more relevant to the American system), but there's also something to be said for the opposite.

$\epsilon-\delta$ language tends to be overly technical; it's simple enough to phrase to 1st year students, and precise enough to practice rigorous mathematics, but all these technicalities can also obscure the point (a la the famous trees-forest analogy). The concepts of open sets and preimages under functions can be somewhat more powerful, and/or point to the crux of the proposition one considers, whereas having to deal with too many quantifiers might be cumbersome.

So, when you see proper math textbooks using seemingly complex constructs to avoid speaking in $\epsilon-\delta$ language, I put forward that most of the time that is done in the name of abstractness, to better phrase underlying concepts, or better deal with new and more general notions the author wishes to present.

---

I had to return here when I encountered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643841/89121), an example where OP did a great job solving a problem with $\epsilon-\delta$ techniques, but still seemed to be feeling uncomfortable with the results. For my money, that's exactly because this language hides the crux of the problem, the reason things work the way they do. Having completed the exercise, I believe OP still wouldn't have pinned the underlying property that's present in the cases for which the answer is 'yes', and absent where it's 'no'.

Comment: Oh no, by no means am I criticizing the generalization of these concepts, as it becomes a must when there's no longer a metric function