# Exercise with Cauchy sequence and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I tried the following exercise:

Give an example of each of the following or state that such a request is not possible. For any that are impossible supply an explanation for why this is the case.

(a) a continuous function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ and a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) $ is not a Cauchy sequence

(b) a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ and a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) $ is not a Cauchy sequence

(c) a continuous function $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ and a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence

(d) a continuous bounded function $f$ on $(0,1)$ that attains a maximum value but not a minimum value (on $(0,1)$)

Please can you tell me if my anwer are correct?

(a) possible: $f(x) = 1/x$ and $x_n = 1/n$.

(b) not possible: $f$ is uniformly continuous. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $\delta >0$ be such that $|x-y|<\delta$ imply $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Then there is $N$ with $n,m>N$ imply $|x_n-x_m|<\delta$ imply $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|<\varepsilon$

(c) like in (a): $f(x) = 1/x$ and $x_n = 1/n$.

(d) $f(x) = x$ if $x\in (0,1/2]$ and $f(x) =1-x$ if $x \in [1/2,1)$.

Comment: Nice; please check your answer to (c).

Comment: @JonathanY. Thank you, I see it is not defined at $0$. I will try to find an other example.

Comment: Keep in mind Cauchy sequences are bounded before trying to find a counterexample for (c).

Comment: @DavidMitra Maybe with $x_n = 1/n$ and $f(x) = \log x$ it works?

Comment: Still not defined at $0$. My previous comment was meant to hint that (c) is true. Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $(x_n)$ Cauchy in $[0,\infty)$. Then $(x_n)$ is bounded, by $M>0$, say. Now $f$ is continuous on $[0,M]$, so ...

Comment: Perhaps I can phrase this differently; $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. This implies that every closed subset is complete as well.

Comment: @JonathanY. Why does completeness of $f([0,\infty))$ imply that $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @DavidMitra So $f(x_n)$ is bounded also. Then it has a convergent subsequence and this must converge to $f(x)$? But even if there is the convergent subsequence the original sequence $f(x_n)$ could still not be Cauchy?

Comment: Now, I can prove that (c) is a true statement but it is not obvious to me.

Comment: If $[0,\infty)$ is closed then $x = \lim_n x_n \in [0,\infty)$. Let $\varepsilon> 0$. If $f$ is continuous at $x$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ imply that $|f(x) -f(y)|<{\varepsilon \over 2}$. Because $x_n$ is Cauchy there exist $N$ such that $m,n > N$ imply that $|x_n - x_m|<\delta$. Then for $m,n > N$ it follow that $|f(x_n) - f(x_m)| \le |f(x_n) - f(x)| + |f(x) - f(x_m)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: in b, how do you know that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're there already, I'll try to add some context.

A continuous function maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences (as far as I know, this result on real functions is ascribed to Heine), and convergent sequences are always Cauchy. Therefore, $(f(x_n))_n$ might fail to be Cauchy only if it fails to converge, and that might occur only if $(x_n)$ fails to converge.

We therefore witness that the exercise is closely linked with the completeness of $f$'s domain. Perhaps the missing part is proving, generally, that whenever $A\subset\Bbb R$ isn't complete, there exists a continuous $f:A\to\Bbb R$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n\subset A$ such that $(f(x_n))_n$ isn't Cauchy. That can be accomplished basically in the same manner you've managed part (a), by picking $x_0\in \overline{A}\setminus A$ and defining $f(x):=\frac{1}{x-x_0}$.

---

With regards to your questions in comments, I was indeed aiming at the fact that any Cauchy sequence in the domain converges (hence the sequence of images also converge, and is therefore Cauchy). In this, it might be easier to let the $\epsilon-\delta$ language rest, and rely on proven results which are more, for lack of a better word, illuminating in this case.

Without presuming to speak for him, I imagine @DavidMitra was hinting that you've basically reduced the problem to the one you dealt with in part (b), which is a different approach than what I had in minds (kudos, BTW).