# Is it true that for Increasing function $f'(x) \ge 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

In Spivak he claims that, "it's easy to see that for an increasing function $f'(x) \ge 0$". How?

Increasing function is defined as: if $x \lt y$, then $f(x) \lt f(y)$. We are also assuming that $f'(x)$ is defined in an open interval $(a,b)$. We are only considering this interval for all the discussion.

Comment: @user54755: No, that won't do it. You're thinking of a converse.

Comment: $\forall x$, either $f'(x)\geq0$ or $f'(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: assume $f'(x)$ exists at a given point $x$, write down its definition (the one with a limit) and tell us what you think.

Comment: Look at it geometrically. $f'(x)$ is the value of the tangent to the function in a given point. So $f'(x)=\tan\varphi$ where $\varphi$ is the angle to the positive direction of the $x$-axis. You only need to look at the properties of the $\tan$ function to understand. You can draw a little triangle with $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$. That is the intiutive proof. A stringent proof would simply start with the definition of the differential (something like nayrb has written, maybe a few more details like solving the limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f:[a,b] \to R$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ and *differentiable* at a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$. Then $f'(x_0) \geq 0$.

Proof: Increasing means that $f(x_0+h) \geq f(x_0)$ for $h > 0$, or dividing by $h$ and rearranging,
$$\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h} \geq 0.$$

From $f(x_0+h) \geq f(x_0)$ and $h>0$ we get $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=\delta$ and $\delta\geq 0$. The limit of the left term of the inequality is the derivation of the function, so we continue as foloows:

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\delta}{h}=f'(x)\geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: Why are you not saying $\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h} \gt 0$ ? By using the argument of "limits respecting inequalities" I can prove that $f'(x_0) > 0$ which is not true.

Comment: @hasan consider $x \mapsto x^3$. This should be sufficient to tell you that sharp inequality cannot be the correct answer.

Comment: @hasan, Good question. Limit respect inequalities, except that they weaken them slightly. So any strict inequality stays the same except is weakened to "equal to and _____ than". I was being a little imprecise.

Comment: @nayrb I would suggest that you add the discussion about the sign preference and the limit calculation. You don't know if the OP knows how to handle the limits.

Comment: @Kurtovic, made community wiki, add what you like.

Comment: I changed the sign on the definition of increasing, as that was probably the place of importance. That way it is increasing and not _strictly_ increasing.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea of limit respecting inequalities from here. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/562528/7624