# Is it true that if $f(x)$ is increasing then $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

We know that if $f'(x)\geqslant 0$ for every $x$ on some interval $I$ then $f(x)$ 
is increasing on $I.$

Is it true that if $f(x)$ have derivative and increasing on $I$ then $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x\in I$?

I have no idea this problem. Can you explain for me? Thank you very 
much!

Comment: If $f$ is increasing, it does not follow that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811519/is-it-true-that-for-increasing-function-fx-ge-0?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is increasing then $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \geq 0$ for all $h \neq 0$ small enough that $x+h$ and $x$ are in $I$, and if $f$ is assumed to be differentiable, then taking the limit as $h \to 0$ gives $f'(x) \geq 0$.